# When should I set the final output camera in maya ?

Tags: modeling, camera

I have a question , Please help me . When to set the final output view camera ? Should I set that before modeling or after finishing the model . I have big confusion on it .

If I set the camera first and start modeling ,If I look through the final camera , Model looks OK in Final Camera , but if I look at Perspective view , It looks horrible :(  . If I model first and then set the camera , model looks fine in the perspective but I don't get the good result through final camera . I can't set the final camera as the reference image .

So how to Solve this . This problem is irritating me . I am getting one view in Perspective and one in Final Camera . I am looking forward for your help .

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to 3D you shouldn't rely on just one viewport to assess your model, you should be moving around the model checking that the shape is correct from all angles (using a perspective view or camera).

If the models seems to only look correct from one angle, your issue could be that the camera is set to orthographic. This is fine when modelling from a particular view (top, front, side etc..) using references or blueprint, but you still have to check the other angles of the mesh to make sure it look correct.

If your modelling a complex mesh, its good practice to create a block out first, which is made of simple primitives, like cubes and cylinders to make sure that you have the correct proportions of the mesh before trying to actually model the detailed mesh.